# Android game crashes if lock button is pressed

Tags: android, crash, game-physics

If I press lock button while my game is in foreground then it calls onStop() and immediately onDestroy() and when I unlock the device only white screen is displayed with background music of the game. But if I press home button (when my game is in foreground) and then press the lock button it only calls onStop() method and if I unlock the device and resume my game it runs perfectly. 
I have overridden onPause() and onResume() method where I am stopping and playing background music. 
What could be the problem if anyone can help me?

Overridden Methods Code:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    if (menu != null) {
        if (menu.currentMenu() != menu.IN_GAME) {
            menu.switchMusic(false);
        } else {
            if (Game != null) {
                Game.switchMusic(false);
            }
        }
    }
    // Logs 'app deactivate' App Event.
    AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this, APP_ID);
    System.out.println("On Pause");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    // Logs 'install' and 'app activate' App Events.
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this, APP_ID);
    if (menu != null) {
        if (menu.currentMenu() != menu.IN_GAME)
            menu.switchMusic(true);
        else
            Game.switchMusic(true);
    }
    System.out.println("On Resume");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    System.out.println("On Stop");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    System.out.println("On Start");
}
```

logcat:

```
02-19 19:19:13.205: I/SELinux(14046): Function: selinux_android_load_priority , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SHV-E210K_4.4.4_0032
02-19 19:19:13.210: E/dalvikvm(14046): >>>>> Normal User
02-19 19:19:13.210: E/dalvikvm(14046): >>>>> com.khubaib.localpakistanigames [ userId:0 | appId:10309 ]
02-19 19:19:13.210: D/dalvikvm(14046): Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-19 19:19:13.605: I/System.out(14046): onCreate
02-19 19:19:13.605: I/com.khubaib.localpakistanigames(14046): PROCESSING onStart
02-19 19:19:13.605: I/System.out(14046): On Start
02-19 19:19:13.605: D/Activity(14046): #1 setTransGradationModeColor false
02-19 19:19:13.645: I/System.out(14046): On Resume
02-19 19:19:13.660: I/System.out(14046): On Pause
02-19 19:19:13.700: D/libEGL(14046): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
02-19 19:19:13.705: D/libEGL(14046): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
02-19 19:19:13.710: D/libEGL(14046): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
02-19 19:19:13.715: E/(14046): Device driver API match
02-19 19:19:13.715: E/(14046): Device driver API version: 29
02-19 19:19:13.715: E/(14046): User space API version: 29 
02-19 19:19:13.715: E/(14046): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Tue Aug 26 17:05:16 KST 2014 
02-19 19:19:13.825: D/OpenGLRenderer(14046): Enabling debug mode 0
02-19 19:19:13.860: I/System.out(14046): OnSaveInstanceState
02-19 19:19:13.860: I/com.khubaib.localpakistanigames(14046): PROCESSING onStop
02-19 19:19:13.860: I/System.out(14046): On Stop
02-19 19:19:35.325: D/dalvikvm(14046): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-19 19:21:06.810: D/dalvikvm(14046): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-19 19:22:18.960: I/System.out(14046): On Restart
02-19 19:22:18.960: I/com.khubaib.localpakistanigames(14046): PROCESSING onStart
02-19 19:22:18.960: I/System.out(14046): On Start
02-19 19:22:19.135: D/Activity(14046): #1 setTransGradationModeColor false
02-19 19:22:19.140: I/System.out(14046): On Resume
02-19 19:22:19.570: I/System.out(14046): On Pause
02-19 19:22:19.570: I/System.out(14046): OnSaveInstanceState
02-19 19:22:19.570: I/com.khubaib.localpakistanigames(14046): PROCESSING onStop
02-19 19:22:19.570: I/System.out(14046): On Stop
02-19 19:22:19.570: I/System.out(14046): On Destroy
02-19 19:22:19.590: W/System.err(14046): Smooth is not supported by this hardware (or driver)
02-19 19:22:19.790: D/dalvikvm(14046): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 984K, 16% free 9535K/11304K, paused 29ms, total 32ms
02-19 19:22:19.855: D/dalvikvm(14046): DexOpt: couldn't find field Lprocessing/core/PApplet;.frame
02-19 19:22:19.855: W/dalvikvm(14046): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 7739
02-19 19:22:19.860: D/dalvikvm(14046): VFY: replacing opcode 0x54 at 0x0002
02-19 19:22:19.860: D/dalvikvm(14046): DexOpt: couldn't find field Lprocessing/core/PApplet;.frame
02-19 19:22:19.860: W/dalvikvm(14046): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 7739
02-19 19:22:19.860: D/dalvikvm(14046): VFY: replacing opcode 0x54 at 0x000b
02-19 19:22:19.860: D/dalvikvm(14046): DexOpt: couldn't find field Lprocessing/core/PApplet;.frame
02-19 19:22:19.860: I/dalvikvm(14046): DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x1e3b at 0x12 in LcontrolP5/ControlWindow;.setUndecorated
02-19 19:22:19.860: D/dalvikvm(14046): DexOpt: couldn't find field Lprocessing/core/PApplet;.frame
02-19 19:22:19.860: I/dalvikvm(14046): DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x1e3b at 0x35 in LcontrolP5/ControlWindow;.setUndecorated
02-19 19:22:19.860: D/dalvikvm(14046): DexOpt: couldn't find field Lprocessing/core/PApplet;.frame
02-19 19:22:19.860: I/dalvikvm(14046): DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x1e3b at 0x44 in LcontrolP5/ControlWindow;.setUndecorated
02-19 19:22:19.870: I/System.out(14046): ControlP5 2.0.4 infos, comments, questions at http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5
02-19 19:22:19.905: D/dalvikvm(14046): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 179K, 15% free 9616K/11304K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
02-19 19:22:19.910: I/dalvikvm-heap(14046): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.621MB for 1536016-byte allocation
02-19 19:22:19.955: D/dalvikvm(14046): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 14% free 11116K/12808K, paused 44ms, total 44ms
02-19 19:22:20.300: D/dalvikvm(14046): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 12% free 12617K/14312K, paused 21ms, total 22ms
02-19 19:22:20.770: D/dalvikvm(14046): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2846K, 19% free 18320K/22384K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
02-19 19:22:20.825: D/dalvikvm(14046): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 277K, 16% free 18838K/22384K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
02-19 19:22:20.865: D/dalvikvm(14046): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 532K, 17% free 19101K/22912K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
02-19 19:22:20.935: D/dalvikvm(14046): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 533K, 16% free 19762K/23440K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
02-19 19:22:21.100: D/dalvikvm(14046): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1389K, 14% free 21025K/24356K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
02-19 19:22:21.210: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(14046): native_setup
02-19 19:22:21.210: V/MediaPlayer(14046): constructor
02-19 19:22:21.210: V/MediaPlayer(14046): setListener
02-19 19:22:21.210: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(14046): reset
02-19 19:22:21.210: V/MediaPlayer(14046): reset
02-19 19:22:21.210: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(14046): setDataSourceFD: fd 74
02-19 19:22:21.210: V/MediaPlayer(14046): setDataSource(74, 57148, 2969)
02-19 19:22:21.210: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(14046): native_setup
02-19 19:22:21.210: V/MediaPlayer(14046): constructor
02-19 19:22:21.210: V/MediaPlayer(14046): setListener
02-19 19:22:21.210: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(14046): reset
02-19 19:22:21.210: V/MediaPlayer(14046): reset
02-19 19:22:21.215: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(14046): setDataSourceFD: fd 77
02-19 19:22:21.215: V/MediaPlayer(14046): setDataSource(77, 14060733, 2555446)
02-19 19:22:21.225: V/MediaPlayer(14046): message received msg=8, ext1=0, ext2=0
02-19 19:22:21.225: V/MediaPlayer(14046): notify(8, 0, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
02-19 19:22:21.235: V/MediaPlayer(14046): message received msg=8, ext1=0, ext2=0
02-19 19:22:21.235: V/MediaPlayer(14046): notify(8, 0, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
02-19 19:22:21.270: V/MediaPlayer(14046): setVideoSurfaceTexture
02-19 19:22:21.270: V/MediaPlayer(14046): setVideoSurfaceTexture
02-19 19:22:21.270: V/MediaPlayer(14046): prepare
02-19 19:22:21.270: V/MediaPlayer(14046): prepare
02-19 19:22:21.280: V/MediaPlayer(14046): message received msg=200, ext1=973, ext2=0
02-19 19:22:21.280: W/MediaPlayer(14046): info/warning (973, 0)
02-19 19:22:21.280: V/MediaPlayer(14046): callback application
02-19 19:22:21.280: V/MediaPlayer(14046): back from callback
02-19 19:22:21.285: V/MediaPlayer(14046): message received msg=5, ext1=0, ext2=0
02-19 19:22:21.285: V/MediaPlayer(14046): New video size 0 x 0
02-19 19:22:21.285: V/MediaPlayer(14046): callback application
02-19 19:22:21.285: V/MediaPlayer(14046): back from callback
02-19 19:22:21.285: V/MediaPlayer(14046): message received msg=200, ext1=973, ext2=0
02-19 19:22:21.285: V/MediaPlayer(14046): message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
02-19 19:22:21.285: W/MediaPlayer(14046): info/warning (973, 0)
02-19 19:22:21.285: V/MediaPlayer(14046): callback application
02-19 19:22:21.285: V/MediaPlayer(14046): back from callback
02-19 19:22:21.285: V/MediaPlayer(14046): message received msg=5, ext1=0, ext2=0
02-19 19:22:21.285: V/MediaPlayer(14046): prepared
02-19 19:22:21.285: V/MediaPlayer(14046): signal application thread
02-19 19:22:21.285: V/MediaPlayer(14046): callback application
02-19 19:22:21.285: V/MediaPlayer(14046): prepare complete - status=0
02-19 19:22:21.285: V/MediaPlayer(14046): back from callback
02-19 19:22:21.290: V/MediaPlayer(14046): New video size 0 x 0
02-19 19:22:21.290: V/MediaPlayer(14046): callback application
02-19 19:22:21.290: V/MediaPlayer(14046): back from callback
02-19 19:22:21.290: V/MediaPlayer(14046): message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
02-19 19:22:21.290: V/MediaPlayer(14046): prepared
02-19 19:22:21.290: V/MediaPlayer(14046): signal application thread
02-19 19:22:21.290: V/MediaPlayer(14046): callback application
02-19 19:22:21.290: V/MediaPlayer(14046): back from callback
02-19 19:22:21.290: V/MediaPlayer(14046): prepare complete - status=0
02-19 19:22:21.395: I/System.out(14046): onCreate
02-19 19:22:21.395: I/com.khubaib.localpakistanigames(14046): PROCESSING onStart
02-19 19:22:21.395: I/System.out(14046): On Start
02-19 19:22:21.395: I/System.out(14046): OnRestoreInstanceState
02-19 19:22:21.395: D/Activity(14046): #1 setTransGradationModeColor false
02-19 19:22:21.395: I/System.out(14046): On Resume
02-19 19:22:21.405: E/ViewRootImpl(14046): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
02-19 19:22:21.405: I/MediaPlayer(14046): Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
02-19 19:22:21.405: E/MediaPlayer(14046): Should have subtitle controller already set
02-19 19:22:21.405: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(14046): setLooping: 1
02-19 19:22:21.405: V/MediaPlayer(14046): MediaPlayer::setLooping
02-19 19:22:21.405: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(14046): setVolume: left 1.000000  right 1.000000
02-19 19:22:21.405: V/MediaPlayer(14046): MediaPlayer::setVolume(1.000000, 1.000000)
02-19 19:22:21.405: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(14046): start
02-19 19:22:21.405: V/MediaPlayer(14046): start
02-19 19:22:21.445: V/MediaPlayer(14046): message received msg=6, ext1=0, ext2=0
02-19 19:22:21.445: I/MediaPlayer(14046): Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
02-19 19:22:21.445: E/MediaPlayer(14046): Should have subtitle controller already set
02-19 19:22:21.445: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(14046): start
02-19 19:22:21.445: V/MediaPlayer(14046): start
02-19 19:22:21.445: V/MediaPlayer(14046): Received MEDIA_STARTED
02-19 19:22:21.445: V/MediaPlayer(14046): callback application
02-19 19:22:21.445: V/MediaPlayer(14046): back from callback
02-19 19:22:21.455: V/MediaPlayer(14046): message received msg=6, ext1=0, ext2=0
02-19 19:22:21.455: V/MediaPlayer(14046): Received MEDIA_STARTED
02-19 19:22:21.455: V/MediaPlayer(14046): callback application
02-19 19:22:21.455: V/MediaPlayer(14046): back from callback
02-19 19:22:21.470: E/ViewRootImpl(14046): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
02-19 19:22:21.765: V/MediaPlayer(14046): message received msg=2, ext1=0, ext2=0
02-19 19:22:21.765: V/MediaPlayer(14046): playback complete
02-19 19:22:21.765: V/MediaPlayer(14046): callback application
02-19 19:22:21.765: V/MediaPlayer(14046): back from callback
02-19 19:22:21.765: V/MediaPlayer(14046): message received msg=7, ext1=0, ext2=0
02-19 19:22:21.765: V/MediaPlayer(14046): unrecognized message: (7, 0, 0)
02-19 19:22:21.765: V/MediaPlayer(14046): callback application
02-19 19:22:21.765: V/MediaPlayer(14046): back from callback
02-19 19:22:25.580: I/System.out(14046): surfaceTouchEvent!!
02-19 19:22:25.580: E/InputEventReceiver(14046): Exception dispatching input event.
02-19 19:22:25.580: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at com.khubaib.localpakistanigames.LocalPakistaniGames.surfaceTouchEvent(LocalPakistaniGames.java:205)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at processing.core.PApplet$SketchSurfaceViewGL.onTouchEvent(Unknown Source)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8259)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2461)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2150)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2461)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2150)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2461)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2150)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2332)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1616)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2656)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2280)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8467)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4816)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4677)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4235)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4289)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4258)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4369)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4266)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4235)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4289)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4258)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4266)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4235)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6590)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6486)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6457)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6422)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6670)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:131)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
02-19 19:22:25.590: E/MessageQueue-JNI(14046):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 19:22:25.590: D/AndroidRuntime(14046): Shutting down VM
02-19 19:22:25.590: W/dalvikvm(14046): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42586c08)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046): Process: com.khubaib.localpakistanigames, PID: 14046
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at com.khubaib.localpakistanigames.LocalPakistaniGames.surfaceTouchEvent(LocalPakistaniGames.java:205)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at processing.core.PApplet$SketchSurfaceViewGL.onTouchEvent(Unknown Source)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8259)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2461)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2150)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2461)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2150)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2461)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2150)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2332)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1616)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2656)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2280)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8467)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4816)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4677)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4235)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4289)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4258)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4369)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4266)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4235)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4289)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4258)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4266)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4235)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6590)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6486)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6457)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6422)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6670)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:131)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
02-19 19:22:25.595: E/AndroidRuntime(14046):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 19:22:28.770: I/Process(14046): Sending signal. PID: 14046 SIG: 9
```

Comment: hard to say, I think we need to see some code...

Comment: have You set the noHistory attribute to the activity in Your manifest?

Comment: no I havent.....
I am just using name and screenOrientation attribute in activity in manifest

Comment: try to set the following attributes: android:noHistory="true" (Added in API 3) and android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" . (screenSize added in API13). But this depends on which API You are working.

Comment: Ok I will do that and I am using API11 (min) and API(21) target

Comment: screenSize is not available. screenLayout is available. Should I use screenLayout?

Comment: no, that will not help, because screenLayout is only for changes of ui, for example if You set another content view. But try it without this, maybe the noHistory attribute will help.And I saw, sorry for my mistake, set noHistory="false", not to true as I said above...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I followed your instructions but still the same problem